# What are probable interview questions for 5-8 years experienced manual QA Role?

Tags: manual-testing

I am senior QA enginner working as Manual tester with some basic selenium knowledge. I want to switch company & in process of preparing for interview.

Comment: It is worth sharing the question that you have already got ready to. So that we won't duplicate them.

Comment: Be prepared to a "why are you a manual tester after so many years"

Comment: @Rsf - are you suggesting that all manual testers should want to become non-functional testers after a certain amount of years? What about the manual QA who are happy being functional testers, or want to push towards Test Management?

Comment: @trashpanda I am not suggesting anything, but some interviewers might, even as a kind of "let's see how does she get out of it" question

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! Yes its most critical /important question but difficult to answer.Yes I am keen interested in functional tests but would it be enough answer?

Answer (score 4):

Well.. Actually 5-8 years is not that much. However apart from the questions about test techniques, technologies and some theory coupled with your experience I would prepare the set of questions that would expose what was the way you've been developing yourself during your career.

- About the books you've read
- About the conferences you attended
- About the footprint you left (articles, blog posts, volunteering)
- About the cases when you helped others to grow professionally

Since you're mentioning basic Selenium knowledge I would get ready for the questions on that topic as well as more deep dive into the web technologies since they underlie Selenium (HTTP, HTML, DOM, CSS, xPath, etc.).

I would also value the way how the candidate discloses the topic stated in the question. What details they consider important and which ones they omit.

Comment: I never thought about this! Thank you for new perspective!

Answer (score 4):

For the given level of experience, I would go for the following ones as starters:

> - How do you test differently an desktop medical application vs. an online shopping app(web& mobile) vs. gaming console application?
> - What domain expertise you gained working as Manual QA?
> - What unique challenges you faced & overcome  in the QA process working in different projects?
> - What unique do you bring to the table as a QA professional?

and then follow-ups based on answers to drill down further...

Comment: +1 for tasking with a specific problem to solve, and not just asking about experience. I have rejected a few candidates that were great at describing their experience but couldn't solve a single problem.

Comment: Yes, agreed 100%. Lot of candidates can talk about everything under the sun at length comfortably but cannot reverse a string in code.

Comment: That's what makes it my litmus test.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to what Alexey said (if the hiring process is anyway good):

- They will ask about company-specifc problems - so, knowing the business and its history is important;
- They will ask how you help others to develop themselves (testers and non-testers);
- They will ask about how you can help a project besides testing/technical specific tasks.

OBS: If they don't, put this on the table and you will stand out :D

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the aforementioned. I guess you may be given an e-commerce or wallet related realistic scenario to check your approach on testing and exploring the details. As an example, how would you test wallet refund functionality?

Also, Restful APIs are a trend these days. Please get familiar with RESTFUL basics, HTTP Methods and HTTP Codes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Below are some of the questions that would be useful in entering  [top software testing companies](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company):

1. What is Requirement Traceability Matrix?

   2. What is difference between Pilot and Beta testing?
   3. Describe how to perform Risk analysis during software testing?
   4. What is difference between Master Test Plan and Test Plan?
   5. How to deal with not reproducible bug?
   6. What is the role of QA in a project development?
   7. What is concurrent user hits in load testing?
   8. What is the Process for creating a test script?
      9.How to overcome the challenge of not having input documentation for testing?
   9. What are the Roles and Responsibilities of an onsite coordinator?
   10. Mobile Application Testing – What does it include ?
   11. How is traceability of bug follow?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue your career in Manual QA Testing, then you must be certified in ISTQB Foundation Level(I hope you already are :) )

1. You should go through ISTQB Foundation syllabus once again as most of the questions would appear from it.
2. Pesticide paradox, difference between Test Plan and Test Strategy, state transition diagram are some of the concepts they could ask
3. You could also be asked to write functional test cases for a Lift, escalator, email functionality etc.,
4. Different type of tools that you use in your BAU. Eg: HP ALM, JIRA, Selenium,SOAP UI, Jenkins etc
5. If it is Selenium, then they would definitely ask about Action class, exception handling etc.,
6. If you are into Agile model, then you should explain how well you interact with the team, update your stories in JIRA, basically your value add to the team is what the interviewer would want to know
7. Domain knowledge is important too. You should be able to explain a functionality that you have tested
8. Above all, be confident!!

Comment: Unfortunately, having ISTQB certificate does not prove someone can test.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in presenting yourself as someone who wants to do more with Selenium, a quick tip is to familiarize yourself with the Page Object model and be prepared to discuss it.